# store PropertyGroup in an external file

Tags: python

i tried to use python pickle to dump a PropertyGroup to a file and try to restore it, but pickle can't dump the class and gives an error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.SI_type'>: attribute lookup
 __main__.SI_type failed
```

is there a way to dump a PropertyGroup to a file, or it's values then reconstruct the object on load, maybe?

---

example with the problem:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *

print("-"*60)

class MyPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = StringProperty()
    index = IntProperty()
    value = FloatProperty()

bpy.utils.register_class(MyPropertyGroup)

class Mytype(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    lista = CollectionProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)
    listaIndex = IntProperty(default=0)

bpy.utils.register_class(Mytype)
bpy.types.Scene.Mytype = PointerProperty(type = Mytype)

mytypes = bpy.context.scene.Mytype

item = mytypes.lista.add()
item.name = 'foo'
item.index = 42
item.value = 3.1416

dict_test = bpy.context.scene.Mytype["lista"].to_dict()
#AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

import pickle

bytes_test = pickle.dumps(dict_test)

del mytypes["lista"]

dict_test = pickle.loads(bytes_test)

mytypes["lista"] = dict_test

print(
    "name: %s"%mytypes["lista"].test.name,
    "index: %d"%mytypes["lista"].test.index,
    "value: %f"%mytypes["lista"].test.value,
    sep="\n"
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pickle the custom property which saves the data. You can retrieve the dictionary from it with the `.to_dict()` method.

```
import bpy

print("-"*79)

class MyPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    index = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    value = bpy.props.FloatProperty()


bpy.utils.register_class(MyPropertyGroup)
bpy.types.Object.test = \
    bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)

obj = bpy.context.object
#assign some data to test!
obj.test.name = "foo"
obj.test.index = 42
obj.test.value = 3.1416

#if you haven't assigned any data to the attributes of obj.test
#obj["test"] may not exist
#the expression statement
obj.test
#will create obj["test"] with default values then
dict_test = obj["test"].to_dict()

import pickle

bytes_test = pickle.dumps(dict_test)

del obj["test"]
#no data - returns default values
print(
    'del obj["test"]',
    "name: %s"%obj.test.name,
    "index: %d"%obj.test.index,
    "value: %f"%obj.test.value,
    "\n",
    sep="\n"
    )

dict_test = pickle.loads(bytes_test)
obj["test"] = dict_test
print(
    'obj["test"] = dict_test',
    "name: %s"%obj.test.name,
    "index: %d"%obj.test.index,
    "value: %f"%obj.test.value,
    sep="\n"
    )
```

Comment: should i import anything? it don't have .to_dict method with PropertyGroup

Comment: Posted a full example which works for me with 2.69.

Comment: i updated your example with my problem, update the question above.

Comment: You are trying to call `.to_dict` on a list type which is the representation of a `bpy.props.Collection`. If you call it on `dict = bpy.context.scene['Mytype'].to_dict()`, it works fine. In this case it is easier to take `lista` from the dict afterwards `dict['lista']`.

Comment: Or use a list comprehension: `lista = [ elem.to_dict() for elem in bpy.context.scene.Mytype['lista'] ]`