# How to copy objects to another blend file

Tags: python, scripting, baking, operator, command-line

I have my `main.blend` file opened and running. There I have an `operator`, by the execution of which `temporary.blend` gets running in the background (no UI) using `subprocess.run`.

**The Problem:**
How can I copy all mesh objects from `main.blend` and paste them all into `temporary.blend` via script?

**Advanced Problem:**
How can I somehow send properties located in the `PropertyGroup` in the `main.blend` scripts to the `temporary.blend` and send some data from `temporary.belnd` to the `main.blend` back?

Comment: You should try using a [pickle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7027/53513) file. Basically writing Python data as it exists within the interpreted program to an actual file that can be re-read in.

Comment: Great!!! That will work for me! Question about [pickle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/store-propertygroup-in-an-external-file/7027#7027): will the properties stay  if I assign attributes to `obj.test` and then append the obj into another .blend file?

Comment: Yes it should do. You just have to make sure whatever namespace you are creating your object in, is available to the new python script. I'll add an answer with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) file. This filetype allows us to write a Python object to a binary file that can be re-read into another python script.

A few notes.

You have to make sure the objects that you want to refer to are available in the namespace of the new python file you're loading the pkl file into.

Example:

```
# /pickle1.py 

import pickle

# create a custom object
class UserObject:
    def __init__(self, name, adjective):
        self.name = name
        self.adjective = adjective

    @property
    def sentence(self):
        return f"{self.name} is a big {self.adjective}"

# create an instance of the object and write it out.
user = UserObject("Jake", "Butthead")

with open('user.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    data = pickle.dump(user, f)
```

Then in another script we can read that object in.

```
#/pickle2.py

import pickle

# make sure this new file has the same UserObject class imported.
from pickle1 import UserObject

# re-read it in
with open("user.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    jake = pickle.load(f)

print(jake.sentence)
>>> Jake is a big Butthead
```